# Ping/traceroute tool for OSX

Tags: networking, monitoring, mac, ping, graphical-user-interface

Any suggestions for a network monitoring tool for OS X that can do the same functionality like Axence Nettools.

Basically, I want to be able to track ping history and view them as a report. Other nifty features like traceroute, port scanning, etc. would be cool but not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/

It's a tool that combines ping and trace route and can be deployed on linux as well as os x machines.

Comment: Mind expanding on your answer? [Answers that consist of just a link somewhere else are generally frowned upon.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: there you go. I'm a newbie. I hope it looks better though?